# Get the all button's id in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cakephp

In my view file i have two div, in div1 there is some buttons, when i click a button in div1 it goes to div2 and in div2 it does same thing, this time it goes to div1.

Now my question is when there is several buttons in div2, how can i take all the button's id in an array. I want to pass this array in a hidden field of another model.

i tried in following way but it does not working.This is my scripting code.

```
function movebutton(elem){
    var teamMember=[];
    if( $(elem).parent().attr("id") == "officers_list" ){
        $(elem).detach().appendTo('#add_member');
         teamMember.push($(elem).attr("id"));
    }
    else{
        $(elem).detach().appendTo('#officers_list'); 
        teamMember.pop($(elem).attr("id"));

    }
    $("#TeamTeamMember").val(teamMember);

    //console.debug('teamMember=>',teamMember);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here scope of `teamMember` is local .so whenever you invoke your function it will create new empty array
Make it global

```
var teamMember=[];
       function movebutton(elem){
        if( $(elem).parent().attr("id") == "officers_list" ){
            $(elem).detach().appendTo('#add_member');
             teamMember.push($(elem).attr("id"));
        }
        else{
            $(elem).detach().appendTo('#officers_list'); 
            teamMember.pop($(elem).attr("id"));
        }
        $("#TeamTeamMember").val(teamMember);
        //console.debug('teamMember=>',teamMember);
    }
```

or You could use [**`$.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function

```
var teamMember = $("#add_member").find("button").map(function(){
return this.id;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function. Code below will return an array of ids.

```
$("#divId input[type='button']").map(function(index,element) { return element.id; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 2nd div's id is `div2` and your buttons marked up with the `input` tag, the following should create an array containing all buttons' ids that are in the desired div:

```
var btns = [];
$('#div2 input[type="button"]').each(function() {//if you are using the <button> markup just use $('div2 button').each(..)
   btns.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Hope this helps.